# Creating a Button with Action with Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I"m new to Chrome extensions and have the basics down but I'm confused on one thing. Let's say I want to add a button to a website. Not my website, something I have no control over like Facebook. Right now I use JQuery to add the button to the bottom of a div. Works great. But now I want to do something with that button, like show an alert.

I have this working, but it seems like the wrong way to do it. After I add myBtn to the page, I add a click handler to the body of the page:

```
    $("body").append("<script>$('#myBtn').click(function(){alert('hi')})</script>")
```

Again this works, but it seems like the wrong way to do it. How do I add a button to a page I can't control, and give it a custom action?

Comment: You can just do that directly in the extension JavaScript, you don't need to do an additional insert of a script tag into the page.

Comment: Ah I see I was adding it outside of the listener which of course didn't work, that does work thanks, that looks much better.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Could you please make an answer out of that?

Answer (score 0):

In the same script that you are adding the button, you can add the click functionality:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){alert('hi')});
```

Just because you are adding it (locally) to a site that you have no control over does not change how the browser interprets this javascript.

Comment: Well, that's a wrong assumption. It _does_ change, because of [isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). But DOM and DOM events are mostly shared, so this works.